# How to use IF and INDEX if a number falls in a table of ranges

Tags: excel, formulas

I am trying to create a new budget template with the data I was given. I was able to summarize the data and minimize it to a table. I am trying to use an INDEX MATCH with an IF formula within a certain range. Here is my example data table:

[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by6cX.jpg)

My two pieces of data would be the closing time and attendance.

for example, if the attendance is 17,000 and we close at 10:00 PM, I need the cell to run an IF between numerous ranges and time.

I am a little stumped on how I would approach the numerous ranges that my attendance of 17,000 would have to run.

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX/MATCH/MATCH

```
=INDEX(A:I,MATCH(17000,A:A),MATCH("10:00 PM",2:2,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh I see, but what about the 17,000. I need the 17,000 to be able to match between two ranges of numbers. So if the 17000 falls between 15,001 and 19,000 then it searches for the time. Will I use a Nested IF formula there?

Comment: No, Look at the formula in the formula bar.  It is looking for 17000 and it ends up on the row that starts with 15001.  The second MATCH is relative match.  do not worry about the upper end.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I was testing the formula and copying down the other cells. But I forgot to lock  certain cells: =INDEX($X$21:$AD$27,MATCH(G20,V21:V27),MATCH(E20,$X$20:$AD$20,0))   thank you for your help!!